# how can i say `from beginning to $string` and `from $string to the end` in regexish for php

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove a part from a text till the given string, and remove another part starting from another string in php.

/.+string/i and /anotherstring.+/i didn't work.

Comment: just to be clear, you're trying to match all text before one keyword, and all text after another? In each case you want to remove the matched text?

Comment: Please post the code you used that didn't work.

Comment: $codehtmlfir = preg_replace("/^.*html/i", " ", $cahtml, 1);

this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

`/^.*$string/` and `/$string.*$/`.

Comment: i tried, 
$codehtmlfir = preg_replace("/^.+html/i", " ", $cahtml, 1);

makes nothing

Comment: $codehtmlfir = preg_replace("/^.*html/i", " ", $cahtml, 1);
doesn't work

Comment: @hyilmaz: You have to use them in the same statement I'd assume... `/^.*html/i`  will replace the entire string from the beginning until it reaches 'html' somewhere with a space.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use too much regex.

```
$str = "junk junk keyworD1 what i want1 keYWord2 junk junk keyWORD1 what i want2 KEYWORD2";
$s  = preg_split("/keyword1|keyword2/i",$str);
for($i=1;$i<count($s);$i+=2){
 print $s[$i]."\n";
}
```

from the above , `$s[1]` will be what you want after `keyword1`. If there are multiple keyword pairs, the stuff you want are at every 2nd position. ie `$s[1],$s[3]` and so on.

output

```
$ php test.php
what i want1
what i want2
```

Comment: Ok, and what about minor and major letters. sometimes it can be Keyword or keyWord

Comment: then use `preg_split` with `i` modifier

Answer (score 0):

'regexish' is a bit more complex than that, so you have to be more precise about what you want

from beginning to the *first* occurrence of string, but stop on the newline

```
/^.*?string/
```

from beginning to the *last* occurrence of string, stop on the newline

```
/^.*string/
```

from beginning to the last occurrence of string, ignoring newlines

```
/^.*string/s
```

from beginning to the last occurrence of string, ignoring newlines and case

```
/^.*string/si
```

etc etc